# how to find common words from a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Hi I am a bit new to Haskell programming. I just wanted to know how I can find 10 common words from a list in Haskell.

Example of a list:

```
["there", "is", "is", "a", "man", ...]
```

Example usage:

```
getCommonWords xs = count(10, xs)
```

And how can I drop 10 common words from the list:

```
removeCommonWords xs = drop(10, xs)
```

Any help or right direction would very thankful.

Comment: Define "common words" - words that are the same? If so, what does the `10` in your proposed `count` function signify? Please expand your examples more to provide a [mcve] that we can work with.

Comment: `drop (10, xs)` is a type error. The first argument to `drop` must be a number, not a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may get you started

```
commonwords n = snd . unzip . take n . reverse . sort . map pair . group . sort
     where pair x = (length x, head x)
```

to filter out blacklisted words

```
filterBlackList = filter (`notElem` blacklist)
```

you need to combine the two...

Here is one trivial way to connect the two functions

```
removecommon :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
removecommon n ws = filter (`notElem` commonwords n ws) ws
```

for example

```
> let ws = words "she sells seashells by the seashore the shells she sells are surely seashells so if she sells shells on the seashore I'm sure she sells seashore shells"

> removecommon 6  ws
```

gives back

```
["by","are","surely","so","if","on","I'm","sure"]
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it will certainly help thanks

Comment: can you please let me know how can i find 10 most frequently used words appeared in the text?

Comment: For example i should get the out put in integer for e.g 12

Comment: Thank you so much, i have got one more little question as well, i just want to know how can we get the number of times altogether the most common 20 words appeared.

Comment: that will require a new function since we drop the counts after sorting, but check the first function, remove `snd` and instead write a `sum` on the `fst`.  If this is a homework I already past the limit. Try-error is part of learning.  Ask again if you can't get anywhere...